# How to access the password reset token inside `emails.auth.reminder`?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have just started learning Laravel and I was following the documentation. I got to know that Laravel uses `emails.auth.reminder` view to be sent as an email to the user with the reset `token`. In my `emails.auth.reminder`, I have put the following:

```
Hello Dear User,<br><br>
We have received a request from your account to reset your password at Larblog. Please use the following link to reset your password.<br><br>

{{ URL::to( 'user/resetpassword/' . Session::get('_token') ) }}<br><br>

If it wasn't you who tried to reset the password, simply ignore this email.<br><br>
Thanks,<br>
- Larblog
```

Notice that, I am using `Session::get('_token')` to access the token. Is it the right way that I am doing it? As it's always generating the same token.`Z7vKMT5ssfzeXsQcVkrYodoRmYnbjH0prdP83jBk` again and again. And when I use this to reset the password, it says: `Invalid token received`. Also, I have checked in the `password_reminders` table of my database and it's showing different token. When I use the token stored in the database, it works.

So, what's right way to access the token in the view that is sent via email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain what the method is to access a password reminder token directly, however normally when sending the email it's done via the Password::remind() function, rather than the usual email function. When using this the $token variable is automatically passed into the email view so that you can use it.

An example use of this function is:

```
Password::remind(Input::only('email'), function ($message)
{
    $message->subject('Password Reset');
});
```

And then accessing it in the view is as simple as:

```
To reset your password, complete this form: {{ URL::to('reset', array($token)) }}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your valuable answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The _token in the session isn't the password reminder token - it's [the CSRF token](http://laravel.com/docs/security#protecting-routes) automatically inserted for security reasons.

Since I don't know what your tables and models look like, it's hard to say exactly how you should get the actual password reminder token, but it's likely something like this:

```
$user = User::find($someid);    // first fetch your user
$token = $user->passwordReminder->token; // now get the token
```

If your tables and models differ from my assumption, feel free to update your question and I'll be happy to update my answer. :)